# Opening of applications for PhD in computer science at UCL,King's College London

Tags: phd, application, computer-science, united-kingdom

I am a Master's student studying computer science in India. I will be applying for a PhD in computer science in the UK beginning in October 2020. UCL and King's college have not updated any details for the academic year 2020/21 yet, they still have the details of last year. Can someone provide some information as to when they open? Some sources say that PhD applications are processed on a rolling basis, i.e. as and when they come, they are passed on to the respective supervisor, and there are no deadlines per se.

Any information on scholarship deadlines would be immensely helpful. I'm referring to the UCL's GRS and ORS, and King's international PGR scholarships (the webpage seems to be down). It is recommended that one applies as soon as possible for the scholarships, but is it possible to apply some time later and still avail them? If say they start applications in December 2019, can i submit an application in February 2020 and still have a reasonable chance to avail those scholarships? I'm an overseas student, and as such a very few fully funded scholarships are available. If there is a lot of competition for those slots, then I think it would be better to apply as soon as they open, otherwise I'll wait for some time, so that I can improve my profile and have a better shot by applying a couple of months later.

Comment: Have you thought about asking UCL or KCL yourself?

Comment: I did, they said it would happen soon. I just need an approximate time, because i couldn't find a single month or date online. KCL says July is the last month for applying to an October start, that's about it.

Comment: Ask the universities your questions directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you should see applications for the upcoming year open in mid to late October in the UK. This allows the admissions offices and administration offices to deal with the students who have made a September or October start before the floodgates open again.

Regarding University-specific scholarships, you will gave to talk directly to the universities in question.